# Win32 dialog is not shown when adding a custom control

Tags: winapi, dialog

I just created a simple Win32 application with the VS2022 wizard.

I opened the About box dialog resource, and I added a "Custom Control" from the Toolbox.
Now, the About box is NOT shown anymore when I run the application.

Here is how the .rc file looks like:

```
IDD_ABOUTBOX DIALOGEX 0, 0, 170, 62
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "About win32_project"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    ICON            IDI_WIN32PROJECT,IDC_STATIC,14,14,20,20
    LTEXT           "win32_project, Version 1.0",IDC_STATIC,42,14,114,8,SS_NOPREFIX
    LTEXT           "Copyright (c) 2023",IDC_STATIC,42,26,114,8
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,113,41,50,14,WS_GROUP
    CONTROL         "Custom1",IDC_CUSTOM1,"",WS_TABSTOP,28,41,50,14
END
```

The problem seems to be related to the "Custom Control".
If I remove it, the About dialog box is shown.

Comment: The [`CONTROL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/control-control) statement must provide a valid window class (either a name or a 16-bit value). `""` is not a valid window class.

Comment: @IInspectable
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the IInspectable's suggestion:

The [CONTROL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/control-control) statement must provide a valid window class (either a name or a 16-bit value). "" is not a valid window class.